# Has `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` moved?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to configure log rotation on my Ubuntu machine so that logs are rotated every day and kept for 14 days. Most tutorials I find, such as [this one](https://fabianlee.org/2017/04/17/ubuntu-logrotate-for-retention-policy-of-logs/), mention that I should modify `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` but that file does not exist on my computer. Has this file moved or do I need to create it? What file do I need to modify in Ubuntu 16.04 to configure daily log rotation?

Comment: If, as it seems, you have a second question, ASK A SECOND QUESTION. Help later users find your question.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you're broadening their scope which makes them harder to answer. On top of that it likely invalidates existing answers. I took the liberty to revert [the edit](/revisions/932049/2) that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932670/how-can-i-configure-logrotate-without-having-etc-logrotate-d-rsyslog

Answer (score 3):

Begin with `man logrotate`. `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` exists on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS system, and is part of the `rsyslog` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
rsyslog: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

Comment: I updated my question with more information. Can you see if you could help me more to find out what the issue is? Thanks!